# Can a flutter app run code on receiving a push notification while Not Running

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I have push notifications working and have both a data and notification part in them.  In the data part is a tag that tells the app what updates are available for the user.

The problem is that I would like the app to fetch those updates even if the user does not tap on the notification.

With other apps, eg Whatsapp, a notification is shown.  Without tapping this notification, and even when the app is not running, the app downloads the data.  For example if the user switches to flight mode right after receiving the notification and then opens whatsapp, the message and/or picture is there, already downloaded and displayed in the app.

So the question is how to get an app written in Flutter to download something in response to getting a push notification, regardless of whether the app is in the foreground, background, or not running.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout `isolate` mentioned in [Flutter background processes](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes) with a link to Medium [Executing Dart in the Background with Flutter Plugins and Geofencing](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124)

Checking with GitHub issue [Flutter should provide an abstraction for background execution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3671#issuecomment-438113161) and issue comments/references after that you may find some other examples. Bottom line is people need more examples.

Comment: I'm going to take another shot at the Geofencing thing - last time I looked at it it was just way too riddled with specifics relating to Geofencing that made it impossible for me to relate to just the parts I need to "download a link" on being triggered by a Push Notification.